# PHP script terminates abruptly, Apache status 200

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I have a CakePHP 3 script that processes a large dataset and thus runs for an hour or more. However, most of the times script just dies before completion, and I cannot find the reason why. The same happens when calling through a web browser or via `wget --timeout=0 URL` from the shell.

The script sends the data as it is being processed, running `flush()` after each data record. The script terminates within a loop where there are no `exit()` or similar calls.

The things I looked into:

- `set_time_limit(0)`, `ini_set('memory_limit', -1)` are set.
- called `register_shutdown_function()` - the shutdown function does not get called.
- Set Apache timeout to be longer than the expected script execution.
- Checked Apache error log - no errors logged, status code is 200.
- Checked CakePHP logs - no errors logged.
- If MySQL connection got terminated, I should get a CakePHP error, so that is unlikely.

Comment: Are you running out of memory? Even with `ini_set('memory_limit', -1)` your machine only has so much. Use a system monitoring tool (e.g. `top`) to see.

Comment: The HTTP 200 is weird, though. It probably means your script is exiting with a 0 value. We'd have to see it to have any idea why it's exiting successfully before you expect.

Comment: I just tried manually killing PHP (`kill PID`) and Apache shows the same status code 200. I think something is killing PHP. However, if it ran out of memory I would probably see the oom-killer being invoked, and I don't see such messages in the system logs.

Comment: Are you running fcgi php? Look in the apache error log. There are some timeouts for fcgi that immediately terminate the process and this would be one example of when register_shutdown would not get called. I ran into this and it wasn't obvious.

Comment: I am using Cpanel/WHM, it does run PHP as CGI - but there are no errors in the apache log at the time the script terminates.